# How do I navigate after login in Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

In my Blazor Webassembly app, I'm trying to hook into the authentication workflow so that I can direct my users to a specific page within my application after they successfully log in. My identity provider is Auth0, and all of that is working fine, but I can't get my application to redirect to where I want AFTER it finishes the round trip with Auth0.

I've tried:

- Setting a method to the OnLogInSucceeded in my RemoteAuthenticatorView that uses the NavManager to redirect to my intended landing page; this does nothing that I can see
- Setting an action in the CompletingLoggingIn child element of the RemoteAuthenticatorView; this succeeds for a moment before redirecting again to the index
- Hooking into the AuthenticationStateChanged event on the AuthenticationStateProvider to use the NavManager to redirect; this does nothing that I can see

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to call NavigationManager with forceLoad parameter being set to **true**
`Navigation.NavigateTo("counter", true);`
where Navigation is an injected instance of NavigationManager class

Comment: I appreciate your reacting to the feedback you got in comments by editing your post. But please understand that an answer post should be restricted to answering. Please do not again add the non-answering parts which I now removed (twice).